# Rails 4 does not receive http post content, but worked in Rails 3

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an android application exporting data to a rails server. When I use Rails 3, everything is fine and works. But in Rails 4 the server receive instead of the content only the following parameters:

```
{"action"=>"export", "controller"=>"trainings"}
```

The content is sent by the following:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(link);
String xmlFile = createXml(locationList);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlFile, "UTF-8");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

And recieved by Rails with the following code:

```
begin
  if !params[:training].nil? && !params[:training][:location].nil? && !params[:training][:datetime].nil?
    locations = params[:training][:location]

    if locations.count > 0
      training = Training.create! created_at: Time.at((params[:training][:datetime].to_i/1000))

      locations.each do |xml_location|
        if !xml_location["latitude"].nil? && !xml_location["longitude"].nil?
          Location.create! latitude: xml_location["latitude"], longitude: xml_location["longitude"], training_id: training.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
rescue TimeoutError => e

end
```

An example for the body is the following xml:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
 <training>
   <datetime>1409332572032</datetime>
   <location>
     <longitude>-122.084095</longitude>  
     <latitude>37.422005</latitude>
   </location>
   <location>
     <longitude>-122.084095</longitude>
     <latitude>47.422005000000006</latitude>
   </location>
   <location>
     <longitude>-132.08409333333333</longitude>
     <latitude>47.422005000000006</latitude>
   </location>
   <location>
     <longitude>-142.08409333333333</longitude>
     <latitude>47.422005000000006</latitude>
   </location>
 </training>
```

Although I searched for changes from Rails 3 to 4, I couldn't find anything which could cause this behavior change.

Answer (score 1):

One of main difference b/w rails3 and rails4 on how to handle params safely is strong_parameters. You are trying to access to params[:training] directly which is not allowed in Rails4. Here is possible solution.

add training_params function in your controller(TrainingController?):

```
private:
  def training_params
    params.require(:training).permit(:location, :datetime)
  end
```

then use training_params instead of params. ex: `training_params[:location]`

Please also refer https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters for more inforamtion about strong_parameters.

Comment: Trying to apply your solution just throws the following error:

Started POST "/export" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-30 14:17:32 +0200
Processing by TrainingsController#export as HTML
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: training):
app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb:57:in `training_params'
app/controllers/trainings_controller.rb:21:in `export'

Comment: Could I see what POST data look like? that looks like you are not posting "training" parameter?

Comment: I looks like rails is dropping now the data of the http post, because in Rails 3 it works without problems. The post data is: {"action"=>"export", "controller"=>"trainings"} and I got it with training_params.inspect whereby training_params is params.permit!